# Instance v state variables in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react.js, is it better to store a timeout reference as an instance variable (this.timeout) or a state variable (this.state.timeout)?

```
React.createClass({
     handleEnter: function () {
         // Open a new one after a delay
         var self = this;
         this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
             self.openWidget();
         }, DELAY);
     },
     handleLeave: function () {
        // Clear the timeout for opening the widget
        clearTimeout(this.timeout); 
     }
    ...
})
```

or

```
React.createClass({
     handleEnter: function () {
         // Open a new one after a delay
         var self = this;
         this.state.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
             self.openWidget();
         }, DELAY);
     },
     handleLeave: function () {
        // Clear the timeout for opening the widget
        clearTimeout(this.state.timeout); 
     }
    ...
})
```

both of these approaches work. I just want to know the reasons for using one over the other.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html): *"**NEVER** mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable."*

Comment: Tip: Use React’s autobinding: `this.timeout = setTimeout(this.openWidget, DELAY);`

Comment: What should DELAY be set to?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I suggest storing it on the instance but not in its `state`. Whenever `state` is updated (which should only be done by [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) as suggested in a comment), React calls `render` and makes any necessary changes to the real DOM.

Because the value of `timeout` has no effect on the rendering of your component, it shouldn't live in `state`. Putting it there would cause unnecessary calls to `render`.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to what @ssorallen said, you should also remember to handle the component unmounting before your handleLeave is called.

```
React.createClass({
     handleEnter: function () {
         // Open a new one after a delay
         this._timeout = setTimeout(function () {
             this.openWidget();
         }.bind(this), DELAY);
     },
     handleLeave: function () {
        // Clear the timeout for opening the widget
        clearTimeout(this._timeout); 
     },
     componentWillUnmount: function(){
        // Clear the timeout when the component unmounts
        clearTimeout(this._timeout); 
     },
    ...
});
```