# Storing page no in props for infinite scroller in react

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to reactjs. I have implemented infinite scrollable list that loads new topic for the selected category. I am storing pageNo in props and directly changing it using `this.props.pageNo = this.props.pageNo + 1` whenever we scroll to bottom of the page.

```
var TopicList = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return { page: 0 }
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      topics: []
   }
  },
  loadMoreTopics: function(event) {
    var main_section = event.target;
    var scroll = (main_section.scrollHeight - main_section.scrollTop) < (main_section.scrollHeight/2);
    if(scroll) {
      this.props.page = this.props.page + 1;
      this.loadTopics(); // inside loadTopics I am using this.props.page to send the ajax request
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="main-section" onScroll={this.loadMoreTopics}>
        {this.props.topics.map(function(topic) {
          <Topic topic={topic}/>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

I have few questions regarding above code.

1) Is it good  to store such information(pageNo) in props or should I use state. I think it should be in state as its private to the App component and will never be passed to App component from any parent.

2) If I use state to store pageNo then can I use `this.state.pageNo = this.state.pageNo + 1` without using setState as I do not want to re render component when pageNo is changed, but rerender should take place after loadtopics() is called and topics state is updated. I know `this.state.pageNo = this.state.pageNo + 1` works, but I want to know whether it is the right way to do it.

Note: I do not want to rerender when pageNo changes.

Comment: you should store pageNo in state, try to call this.forceUpdate() after the increment

Comment: @PaulBooblic: Thanks for the input. Can you eloborate on why props may be a bad choice. And also I don't want to rerender. Re rendering would be automatically done after successfully completion of ajax call in loadTopic() function as topics state would be updated.

Comment: elements, whitch changes needs to rerender should stored in state, props not provide it. if you need to rerender after successful ajax call - insert this.forceUpdate ot this.setState inside success ajax callback, don't forget to append .bind(this) to success function

Comment: @PaulBooblic: props too provide rerendering facility when it get mutated using setProps. But i don't want to rerender at all when pageNo changes. So no meaning in calling forceUpdate()

Comment: @RohanPujari I am facing a similar issue. What did you decide finally and why?

Comment: @detj: I used component instance variable. Directly use `this.variableName = "value"` in such case. You can check one of the SO answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207703/instance-v-state-variables-in-react-js