# React.createClass with custom properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to treat custom javascript properties in `React.createClass()` ?

Here is example:

```
var RouterView = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Morearty.Mixin],
  isAuthorized: false,      // should it be part of state ??
  isVerified: false,        // should it be part of state ??
  bindToAuthorization: function() {
    if(/* blah-blah-blah */) {
      this.isAuthorized = true; 
    }
  },
  render: ...
});
```

Seems like `.isAuthorized` and `.isVerified` semantically should act like component's state, but it is just properties of `.createClass()` specification.

How `.isAuthorized` and `.isVerified` acts? Is it acts like `static`? Can't found anything about this in React's doc.

Comment: This is what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207703/instance-v-state-variables-in-react-js/25208809#25208809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where the authorisation takes place.

If the logic for determining authorisation takes place in the child component - and only in the child component - then it would be in the child component state. Which means `isAuthorized`, `isVerified` would not be props, they would be state in your child component. And `bindToAuthorization` would be defined by the component itself, not its parent.

More likely though, you'll want the authorisation logic at a higher point in your component hierarchy, or outside of it altogether (if using Flux).

Remember that lower order components often don't need any state. The parent component can simply re-render them within different props. That makes your `bindToAuthorization` unnecessary. The parent doesn't need to delegate the authorisation logic to the child component; it simply re-renders it when the relevant properties change.

Comment: You absolutely right in all points, but I was asking a bit different thing. What `isAuthorized` status? It is neither part of props nor state. When it accessible, when it callable?

Comment: It must be in either props or state. The rendered output is always based on props and state.