# How can I store an object in MeteorJS/React in a variable to return later?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

This piece of code is at the bottom of a component named 'Block'.

```
export default theBlockContainer = createContainer(({ params }) => {

  return {
      voteStatus:Meteor.user()['listofvoted'],
    }

}, Block);
```

The code above works perfect, but I want to refactor it.

Is there any way for me to store the "voteStatus:Meteor.user()['listofvoted']" bit into a variable before the return statement, such that the return statement need to only return the variable?

Ideally something like this...

```
export default theBlockContainer = createContainer(({ params }) => {
  let temp = voteStatus:Meteor.user()['listofvoted'],
  return {
      temp;
    }

}, Block);
```

I think I'm missing something fundamental because it seems like a straight forward task, however I have tried this numerous times and in equally numerous ways but only to receive compiler errors.

Comment: Try: `this.setState({  voteStatus: Meteor.user()['listofvoted'] })`. This is using the state of your 'Block' component to store the variable. And then you should be able to `return this.state.voteStatus;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default theBlockContainer = createContainer(({ params }) => {
  this.setState({value: Meteor.user()['listofvoted']});
  return {
      this.state.value;
    }
}, Block);
```

This code will work for you..

Comment: Thanks this does work! However, is there a way to avoid using react states?

Comment: yes you can use store value in this.value = voteStatus:Meteor.user()['listofvoted'] and get by this.value

Comment: but make sure you go through this discussion which is more clear when to use state and when not : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207703/instance-v-state-variables-in-react-js