# Enzyme test issues returns undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to do unit test my React class component using {mount} method. When I try to access the class variable (using this keyword), running the test gives an error of undefined. Example below where this.DataSource evaluate to undefined after calling `mount(<GridComponent recordArr=[1,2,3] />`

```
    export class GridComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          pageRecords: [],
          totalSize: 0
        }
        this.options = {
          page: 1,
          sizePerPage: 10
        }
        this.DataSource = [] //All records will be stored here
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.DataSource = this.props.recordArr
        this.parseProps()
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.DataSource = nextProps.recordArr
        this.parseProps()
      }

      parseProps = () => {
        let pageRecords = []
        if (!_.isEmpty(this.DataSource)) {  //this.DataSource ==>  undefined
          let startIndex = (this.options.page - 1) * this.options.sizePerPage
          let count = (this.options.page - 1) * this.options.sizePerPage + this.options.sizePerPage
          pageRecords = _.slice(this.DataSource, startIndex, count)
        }
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          pageRecords: pageRecords,
          totalSize: this.DataSource.length
        })
      }

      render() {
        ... //Render the records from this.state.pageRecords
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an arrow function expression? Maybe the `this` is enclosed inside your anonymous arrow function expression. Use a debugger and inspect `this`. Try referencing the recordArr prop directly instead of the DataSource private variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.DataSource` as a component state and then use, [Enzyme util setState function:](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.md) in your test case.

```
wrapper.setState({ DataSource: 'somesource' });
```

For example your components's componentWillReceiveProps method will look like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    DataSource: nextProps.recordArr,
  });
  this.parseProps()
}
```

Comment: I can store DataSource inside state. However, this is considered an anti pattern in React, as the recommendation is to store in State data that only needed to be part of the render method, or when changed will re-render the component again (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207703/instance-v-state-variables-in-react-js).

Comment: Also, this.DataSource is helper object to calc pageRecords, which are what I use when rendering the component (in this case I'm using react-bootstrap-table grid library). So having this inside State is possible, but prefer to avoid it if possible

Comment: Understood, in this case why don't you calculate pageRecords from DataSource, after that set it to the you state? as re-rendering component when pageRecords changes is actually what you want (you can also trying to do it in constructor)